# Explode multiple list columns pairs to more rows in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given a dataset as follows:

```
   id          words           tags
0   1  ['Φ', '20mm']  ['xc', 'PER']
1   2  ['Φ', '80mm']    ['xc', 'm']
2   3        ['EVA']         ['nz']
3   4       ['Q345']         ['nz']
```

`df` in the format of list of dict:

```
[{'id': 1, 'words': ['Φ', '20mm'], 'tags': ['xc', 'PER']},
 {'id': 2, 'words': ['Φ', '80mm'], 'tags': ['xc', 'm']},
 {'id': 3, 'words': ['EVA'], 'tags': ['nz']},
 {'id': 4, 'words': ['Q345'], 'tags': ['nz']}]
```

The elements from `words` have correspondent Part-of-speech tagging (POS tagging) in `tags` column.

I hope to convert dataframe to the following format:

```
   id words tags
0   1     Φ   xc
1   1  20mm  PER
2   2     Φ   xc
3   2  80mm    m
4   3   EVA   nz
5   4  Q345   nz
```

How could I acheive that in Pandas? Thanks.

Comment: easier if you shared the source code : ``df.to_dict('records')``. Meanwhile try : [explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) : -> `df.explode(['words', 'tags'])`

Comment: I updated the example data. Pls check. BTW, I try `df.explode(['words', 'tags'])`, it seems generate same result as original one.

Comment: @sammywemmy, this will not work, explode accepts only scalars, it can explode only a single column

Comment: As a note: the accepted answer of the linked duplicate (`df.set_index(['id']).apply(pd.Series.explode).reset_index()`) appears about 3x faster than the accepted answer here in my testing.

Comment: if you are on Pandas 1.3, explode accepts a list/tuple of columns

Comment: Except `id` column, if other columns not need to explode in the data, `df.set_index(['id']).apply(pd.Series.explode).reset_index()` will not work.

Comment: You can add as many columns in the index as needed. `['id', 'col1', 'col2']` etc.

Comment: It raises an error: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can consider first exploding the dataframe with `id` and `words` and the dataframe with `id` and `tags` then you can concat them.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"id":[1,2,3,4],
     "words":[['Φ', '20mm'],['Φ', '80mm'], ['EVA'], ['Q345']],
     "tags": [['xc', 'PER'],  ['xc', 'm'], ['nz'], ['nz']]})

a = df[["id", "words"]].explode("words")
b = df[["id", "tags"]].explode("tags")
pd.concat([a, b], axis=1)
```